# javascript: How to build a function that refers to the variables in my Quiz app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently built a small quiz application, it currently only has two questions.  After all the questions are finished I would like for the app to present a page that says "You made it here" (eventually I'll add more).  However for some reason the final-function feedback of this code is not working.  Where am I going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

var questions = [
{question: "Who is Zack Morris?",
 choices: ['images/ACslater.jpg','images/CarltonBanks.jpeg','images/ZachMorris.jpg'],
 quesNum: 1,
 correctAns: 2},

 {question: "Who is Corey Matthews?",
 choices: ['images/CoryMatthews.jpeg','images/EdAlonzo.jpg','images/Shawnhunter.jpg'],
 quesNum: 2,
 correctAns: 1},

 ];

 var userAnswer  //THis needs to be looked into
 var counter = 0;
 var score = 0;
 var html_string = '';
 var string4end = ''

//function to loop choices in HTML, updates counter, checks answer

var update_html = function(currentQuestion) {
    // put current question into a variable for convenience.

   // put the question string between paragraph tags
   html_string = '<p>' + currentQuestion.question + '</p>';  
   // create an unordered list for the choices
   html_string += '<ul>';
   // loop through the choices array
   for (var j = 0; j < currentQuestion.choices.length; j++) {
      // put the image as a list item
      html_string += '<li><img src="' + currentQuestion.choices[j] + '"></li>';
   }
   html_string += '</ul>';
   $('.setImg').html(html_string);
}

update_html(questions[0]);


$('.setImg li').on('click', function (e) {
   userAnswer = $(this).index();
   checkAnswer();
   counter++;
   update_html(questions[counter]);
   $('#score').html(score);
   showFinalFeedback();
});

//function to identify right question

function checkAnswer () 
{
   if (userAnswer === questions[counter].correctAns)
   {
      score=+100;  
   }
}

function showFinalFeedback ()
{
   if (counter === (questions.length+1))
   {

      string4end = '<p>' + 'You made it here!!!!' + '</p>';  
      $('.setImg').html(string4end);

   }

}




});
```

Comment: The format you have asked your question is not up to standards for this site. "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Could you please explain what's wrong, limit your code to only the minimum, and be less broad about it?

Comment: due to indexing - set `counter` to `1` not `0`. A fiddle would also help a lot in fixing your issue. With a fiddle present one of us would be able to fix this relatively easily.

Comment: There are few commas missing and the block at your `checkAnswer` method is missing a statement. Use something like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) to verify your code

Comment: @RUJordan thanks for the feedback, I have modified the question to specify the function I am looking into.  I thought providing the whole code would allow for everyone to benefit.

Comment: @vector I will create a fiddle for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Vector that you either should start with 1 as Counter initialization or, to check

```
if (counter < questions.length) {
    return;
}
alert('You \'ve made it till here');
```

I also rewrote it in a form of a jquery plugin, maybe a handy comparison to your way of working?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DEb7J/

```
;(function($) {
    function Question(options) {
        if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        this.chosen = -1;
        this.question = options.question;
        this.options = options.options;
        this.correct = options.correct;

        this.toString = function() {
            var msg = '<h3><i>' + this.question + '</i></h3>';
            for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
                msg += '<a id="opt' + i + '" class="answer toggleOff" onclick="$(this.parentNode).data(\'quizMaster\').toggle(' + i + ')">' + this.options[i] + '</a>';
            }
            return msg;
        };

        this.toggle = function(i) {
            var el = $('#opt' + i);
            if ($(el).hasClass('toggleOff')) {
                $(el).removeClass('toggleOff');
                $(el).addClass('toggleOn');
            } else {
                $(el).removeClass('toggleOn');
                $(el).addClass('toggleOff');
            }
        };
    }

    function Quiz(elem, options) {
        this.element = $(elem);
        this.lastQuestion = -1;
        this.questions = [];
        this.correct = 0;

        if (typeof options !== 'undefined' && typeof options.questions !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < options.questions.length; i++) {
                this.questions.push(new Question(options.questions[i]));
            }
        }

        this.start = function() {
            this.lastQuestion = -1;
            this.element.html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.questions.length; i++) {
                this.questions[i].chosen = -1;
            }
            this.correct = 0;
            this.next();
        };

        this.next = function() {
            if (this.lastQuestion >= 0) {
                var p = this.questions[this.lastQuestion];
                if (p.chosen === -1) {
                    alert('Answer the question first!');
                    return false;
                }
                if (p.chosen === p.correct) {
                    this.correct++;
                }
                $(this.element).html('');
            }
            this.lastQuestion++;
            if (this.lastQuestion < this.questions.length) {
                var q = this.questions[this.lastQuestion];
                $(this.element).html(q.toString());
                console.log(q.toString());
            } else {
                alert('you replied correct on ' + this.correct + ' out of ' + this.questions.length + ' questions');
                this.start();
            }
        };

        this.toggle = function(i) {
            if (this.lastQuestion < this.questions.length) {
                var q = this.questions[this.lastQuestion];
                q.toggle(q.chosen);
                q.toggle(i);
                q.chosen = i;
            }
        };
    }

    $.fn.quizMaster = function(options) {
        if (!this.length || typeof this.selector === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }
        var quiz = new Quiz($(this), options);
        quiz.start();
        $(this).data('quizMaster', quiz);
        $('#btnConfirmAnswer').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            quiz.next();
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

$(function() {
    $('#millionaire').quizMaster({
        questions: [
            { 
                question: 'Where are the everglades?',
                options: ['Brazil','France','USA','South Africa'],
                correct: 2
            },
            { 
                question: 'Witch sport uses the term "Homerun"?',
                options: ['Basketball','Baseball','Hockey','American Football'],
                correct: 1
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for your help.  I was able to use the following work around to ensure everything worked:

```
$('.setImg').on('click', 'li', function () {  
userAnswer = $(this).index();
checkAnswer();
counter++;
$('#score').html(score);

if (counter < questions.length)
     {
       update_html(questions[counter]);

      }
else{
         showFinalFeedback();
      }    
});
```